# Devise Authentication

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise, string-comparison

I am new with rails, and I created simple Administrate admin panel, and simple devise authentication, it works good.

When I create users I define are they Admins, Users or Testers in dropDown menu.
So my problem is that I want to check if user is Admin let him in, and if user is anyone else do not let him in. I want to make it as simple as possible so when someone want to log in check field group if it says admin , it is ok.

My code:

AdminUser model

```
    class Adminuser < ActiveRecord::Base
     # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
     # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
     devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

     #before_filter :grupa.eql? "admin"
    end
```

devise config:

```
config.authentication_keys = [:grupa]
```

devise new sesion:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "style.css" %>
```

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do   |f| %>

```
  <div class= "ex" id="rcorners1">

    <h2>Log in for Admin</h2>
    <div>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
    <% :grupa.eql? "Admin" %>
    </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div>
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>

  <% end -%>
  <div class: 'button'>
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
<% end %>
</body>

<%#= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved similar case with a an `access_denied` method, defined in application_controller.rb

```
  def access_denied
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :text => "Unauthorized", :status => 401, :message => "Unauthorized" }
    format.json { render json: {:error => {:code => 401, :message => "Unauthorized"}}, status: :unauthorized }
end
```

Define a `.admin?` method on your user, maybe just checking group membership or whatever you want to do, and then in the controller you want to protect, do something like,

```
def index
  return access_denied unless current_user.admin? 
end
```

alternatively, you could create a helper method that does the check, and then use it as a before_filter if you want to apply the same logic to a whole controller.
something like,

`before_filter :only_allow_admin_users`

Comment: Thanks  for answer, I will try it now. Ahh it is suppose to be simple check if I select in dropDown menu for someone to be an admin, he can access, and if I don't, he can't...

Comment: sure, just add an additional field to the form you use to create new users.  When its just admin or not admin, I store this as a boolean field and then use a checkbox to indicate if admin or not.  Then it makes it easy to check for admin status by `current_user.admin?` wherever you need to know.

Comment: I tried like that and it works perfectly. But I solved my problem like this I went to session controller and I banned everyone to login except where user_id == 1 && user_id == 2 , because they are my admins, and user can not delete them.. Thanks man.. :)